# Is it possible to get latitude and longitude when there is no data connection?

Tags: ios, core-location

Is it possible to get longitude and latitude info while there is neither a cellular nor a WiFi connection?

Comment: Well, there's GPS if your device supports that...

Comment: Thanks for negative , i was expecting this

Comment: you always get what you are expecting to receive, and your question reflects that expectation... try expecting a solution to your problem next time and construct your question accordingly :)

Answer (score 4):

An Apple person said on the dev forums: "All iOS devices with 3G radios have real, true, honest-to-goodness, satellite communicating GPS (this includes all iPhones except the first one, as well as all iPads with 3G)."

Which means that Core Location will return a Location object with latitude and longitude without accessing the internet over wifi or cell phone, because there is a GPS receiver onboard. Attempting to show a map with MapKit will need an internet connection to get the map tiles of course. But just getting the lat/long can be done.

Answer (score 3):

iOS location API kind of isolates you from source of the location (GPS/3G/Wifi whatever). What you get is coordinates, accuracy, timestamp and [others](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html). As you initialize location API you might get old coordinates. You'll need to check the timestamp if they are too old to be useful for you. This can get you last known location which is useful. If there is no Wifi or 3G and you only depend on GPS, it won't work indoors most of the times!

Comment: My client recorded coordinates which are 10km away from actual location. I used "requestAlwaysAuthorization" and once(This may called 2-3 times) "didUpdateToLocation" called i am stopping stopping location update. what could be  reason for huge difference in coordinate?

Comment: What I usually do if I wish to get a correct location once is: I stop location updates if the timestamp is not older that current constant from now. E.g. if the timestamp is not older than 3 seconds from now then I stop updates and use this location. Otherwise I keep location updates on until I get a fresh location.